# How to get device ID in app

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

The application that we are developing in Tizen, is supposed to collect the data from multiple devices. Therefore, I need to send the `device-ID` (or anything which is unique for every watch) along with other collected data.

I would like to know if there is such an API in Tizen to get the `device-ID` or any other unique identifier for the watch.

---

**UPDATED**
I first tried to get device `DUID` using [SystemInfoDeviceCapability](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/wearable/2.3.0/org.tizen.wearable.web.device.apireference/tizen/systeminfo.html#SystemInfoDeviceCapability):

```
var cap = tizen.systeminfo.getCapabilities();
console.log("Or this damn thing: " + cap.duid);
```

But it seems that `duid` is not defined for Tizen-Wearable, I guess!

Then I followed the [manual](https://source.tizen.org/sites/default/files/page/tizen-2.0-compliance-specification-for-mobile-profile-v1.0.pdf), in which it clearly says `SystemInfo.DUID` is the attribute I am looking for. So I tried:

```
tizen.systeminfo.getPropertyValue("http://tizen.org/system/tizenid",
    function (param) {
        console.log("TIZEN-ID: " + param);
    }, function (error) {
    console.log("An error occurred " + error.message);
});
```

This time I get an error, sayin `type mismatch`, which is probably because this key `http://tizen.org/system/tizenid` is not in the list which `SystemInfo` can work with. This [list](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/wearable/2.3.0/org.tizen.wearable.web.device.apireference/tizen/systeminfo.html#SystemInfoPropertyId), only contains:

"BATTERY"

"CPU"

"STORAGE"

"DISPLAY"

"DEVICE_ORIENTATION"

"BUILD"

"LOCALE"

"NETWORK"

"WIFI_NETWORK"

"CELLULAR_NETWORK"

"SIM"

"PERIPHERAL"

"MEMORY"

None of the above gives me a unique ID for the gear S watch. Is there anywhere else I should be looking for this?

Comment: Did you try with this one?
tizen.systeminfo.getCapability("http://tizen.org/system/tizenid")

Comment: No I have not. Does it return the device unique identifier?

Comment: I used the similar one in native app, hope it will work in web app too.

Comment: Any progress on this yet?

Comment: Any update on this? I really need a unique identifier too....

Comment: We have been using a hard-coded variable in the app. This means for every smartwatch we have to modify the program, which is suboptimal. Post your answer if you found a solution for this.

Answer (score 6):

To get the DUID you can use the following:

```
var tizenId = tizen.systeminfo.getCapability('http://tizen.org/system/tizenid');
```

or this one (**note this is not recommended as it will be deprecated in the future**)

```
var tizenId = tizen.systeminfo.getCapabilities()['duid']; // NOT RERECORDED
```

Also beaware that the DUID is **NOT** unique all the time (if you reset the watch you will get a new ID)
So I suggest you use the MAC Address which is unique per hardware:

```
tizen.systeminfo.getPropertyValue("WIFI_NETWORK",function(e){
      console.log(e.macAddress);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look on those two:

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.guides/html/native/system/sysinfo_n.htm#system

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SYSTEM__INFO__MODULE.html

Comment: Tried what you suggested, and updated the question. The problem is still there.